# Remove JSON value from JSONB column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, sql-update

I've been looking for solution for days now but no success yet. I tried different code snippets from other's answers but somehow nothing worked so far.

I would like to remove a JSON data from my JSONB column inside PostgreSQL.

I am trying to delete the next syntax:

```
 {
  "name": "vmi2",
  "path": "efefe\\feff\\\fefefe",
  "type": "Gym"
 }
```

This is what my JSON looks like in PostgreSQL:

```json
[
 {
  "name": "vmi2",
  "path": "efefe\\feff\\\fefefe",
  "type": "Gym"
 },
 {
  "name": "vmi",
  "path": "efefe\\feff\\\fefefe",
  "type": "Gym"
 },
 {
  "name": "vmi3",
  "path": "efefe\\feff\\\fefefe",
  "type": "Gym"
 }
]
```

This is how I append new data into it (Works):

```sql
UPDATE my_users 
SET json_workouts = 
COALESCE(json_workouts, '[]'::JSONB) || '{"name": "vmi3", "path": 
"efefe\\feff\\\fefefe", "type": "Gym"}' 
WHERE username = 'c';
```

And these are the 2 queries I tried to remove data. Neither worked, though I have looked up these codes from the same article( removing and appending queries too):

First 'deleting' query (Doesn't work):

```sql
DELETE FROM my_users
WHERE json_workouts ->> 'name' = 'vmi2';
```

Second 'deleting' query. (Doesn't work)

```sql
UPDATE my_users
SET json_workouts = json_workouts - 'name'
WHERE username = 'c';
```

Comment: why use json, if you have problems with it a normalized structure, would do the same and without handling json

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what exactly you are trying to delete. But anyway, this would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model (then you could indeed use a DELETE statement)

Comment: this looks like you could adaept it for your problem https://rextester.com/BKJ51586

Comment: It is not clear to me what nbk and a_horse_with_no_name suggested, to use properly normalized data. What it is?

Comment: @nbk your solution at rextester is working for me and I found it previously already, however it deletes everything inside the JSONB column. I edited my post to point out what I would like to remove. Also if you could elaborate on your first comment I would be grateful for that!

Comment: instaead of using a JSOn make a new table workouts and te columns you need and

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I found a similar question with your similar answer about normalized data but there I also did not found examples from you. Could you show an example what is the normalized data is about?

Comment: @RobinGergelyfi make that a standard one-to-many relationship between user account and "workout". Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/CGNzri-N?hide=8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to filter out one (or more) elements from the JSON array, based on the `name` property of each element.

One approach unnests the JSON array, filters out unwanted element(s), and then re-aggregates.

Assuming a table like `t(id, js)`, where `id` is the primary key and `js` is a `jsonb` column, you can do:

```
select t.id, jsonb_agg(j.elt order by j.idx) as new_js
from t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.js) with ordinality as j(elt, idx)
where j.elt ->> 'name' != 'vmi2'
group by t.id
```

Here is a small **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2vILnndu)**; for your sample data, the query returns:

| id | new_js |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ { "name": "vmi", "path": "efefe\feff\\fefefe", "type": "Gym" }, { "name": "vmi3", "path": "efefe\feff\\fefefe", "type": "Gym" } ] |

Comment: Thanks a lot! Meanwhile I solved it by reading the JSON and remove the desired part from an ArrayList of HashMaps but your solution is still way better probably, so I will do my best to implement. Thanks again!